# "My feelings about you never..." — what verb can I use?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

I am trying to say *I always have feelings about you* in a different way:

> My feelings for you never *_*_

My first thought was *reduced*, but it seems that *reduce* is for size.

(I remember hearing something similar in some movies, but I can't remember the name of it.)

What's a good word to use here?

Comment: Please explain the context.  Are you, for example, trying to write a love letter?

Comment: @Pitarou no , just some random thought

Comment: Improve? Solidify? Manifest? Impact?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without more context, it's difficult to know, but I'd try "Faded" (means the same as "reduced") or "changed".

Answer (score 8):

Here's some more

- faltered
- diminished
- waned
- wavered

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest *change*, and also I think it's better to use *for you* instead of *about you*:

> My feelings for you never change.

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on what you want, but how about "My feelings for you have not waned"? It's a bit poetic if that's what you're going for. A bit more dramatic: "My feelings for you have not died." If you want straightforward, go for Cool Elf's "change." All the other suggestions are also appropriate. I like TecBrat's "faded," too.

Answer (score 2):

Either "waned" or "wavered" would work well in this situation. You could also try "varied."

Answer (score 1):

I would say *weakened* or *lost*.

Answer (score 1):

I like **diminished**, but **changed** seems to convey your meaning best.

Answer (score 0):

**subside** |səbˈsīd|

> become less intense, violent, or severe: I'll wait a few minutes until the storm subsides.